# electron build with solid-js shows error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, vite, solid-js

I am using my Solid-JS based web app to standalone using Electron, but the app does not work even if it built successfully.
When I check it with developer tool, it shows the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" to my css and index.tsx files.

In React cases, usually just add {"homepage": "./"} to package.json works, but it does not work for my case.

I just share my package.json and electron.ts file to find the problem. (it is in public/ directory)

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-solid-project",
  "author": "AAAA",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "./public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "postinstall": "node ./fix-jest-dom.mjs",
    "start-renderer": "cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start",
    "start-main": "electron .",
    "compile-main": "tsc ./public/electron.ts",
    "start-main-after-renderer": "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && yarn start-main",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently -n renderer, main 'yarn:start-renderer' 'yarn:start-main-after-renderer'",
    "electron-dist": "yarn build && electron-builder --dir --config .electron-builder.config.cjs",
    "predist": "yarn compile-main",
  },
```

electron.ts

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import * as isDev from 'electron-is-dev';
import { join } from 'path';

const baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

let mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null;

function createMainWindow(): void {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1080,
    height: 700,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../index.html')}`);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  mainWindow.on('closed', (): void => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', (): void => {
  createMainWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', (): void => {
  app.quit();
});

app.on('activate', (): void => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createMainWindow();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not seem anything related to SolidJS but due to some malformed file path.

Edit: He was using absolute path in his config file.

> I found out that vite build in my project imports resource files with absolute path.

You need to compile typescript files into JavaScript files in order to run in Electron renderer. So, there is no way to run `index.tsx` directly in Electron.

You application loads `index.html` file but it is not clear how you run your development server. Developers usually use something like this:

```js
if (isDev) {
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
} else {
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}
```

Make sure your `index.html` file includes client code with their right paths.

> In React cases, usually just add {"homepage": "./"} to package.json works

This is not a built-in Electron functionality. You must be using some package that mounts a react router.

If you are missing files in your executable file, make sure you bundle the required files in your final executable. You need to explicitly specify which files will be included in the bundle.

Here is a basic electron-vite-solid app: https://github.com/snnsnn/electron-vite-solid

Comment: In development mode, the code works well. I just removed the part in my example you mentioned because I just want to concentrate on the issue of production build.

I just open the developer tools in the production build to find the errors, and it does not mean that I have an error in development mode.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I compare your code and my project, and I found out that vite build in my project imports resource files with absolute path. I don't know why they imports resources with absolute paths, but I just fix it with adding {"base": ""} to my vite.config.ts file and now the problem solved!